# Django test database requires Postgres Extension enabled

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a Django app which requires Postgres' fuzzystrmatch extension to be enabled on the database.

Django's unittest framework creates and destroys a new database. I need this new database to have the extension turned on for testing.

I can use './manage.py test --keepdb' to keep the database and then manually turn on the extension, but this is an ineloquent solution.

Any idea how I can enable this extension programmatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create an empty migration and use the `CreateExtension` operation:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import CreateExtension

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    ...

    operations = [
        CreateExtension(name='fuzzystrmatch'),
        ...
    ]
```

[Relevant docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#creating-extension-using-migrations)

Edit:
If that doesn't work, reviewing how Django actually handles those classes internally would be my next suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In case you've disabled the migrations in the test settings, the migrations will not be run, so you can't use django `CreateExtension`.

**Example:**

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "test-database",
        "USER": "username",
        "PASSWORD": "password",
        "HOST": "postgresql-host",
        "PORT": "5432",
        "TEST": {
            "MIGRATE": False,
        },
    },
}
```

In this case you can manually call SQL code to create the extension.

If you use unitest, you can for example create a custom TestCase class inherited by all your tests like so:

```
from django.test import TestCase from django.db import connection 
class PostgresExtensionTestCase(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS unaccent;")

        super().setUpClass()
```

If you use pytest, you can create a `fixture` in your `conftest.py` like so (for unaccent in the example):

```
from django.db import connection

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def activate_postgresql_unaccent():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS unaccent;")
```